# Saved job searches: sorting criterion is not saved

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-overflow-jobs, sorting

Steps to reproduce:

- [On the Stack Overflow Jobs site]
- Define some search criteria and press 'Search'
- Select an alternative sort order in the 'Sort by' dropdown, say 'newest'
- Click 'Save search and create alert'
- Go to 'Saved job searches' and click on the just saved one
- The resulting list is sorted by matches instead of by newest

If saving the sorting criterion was not intended initially, I would raise a feature request for this. I believe it is very handy to save searches with users' preferred sort order instead of making them do a couple of extra clicks to re-sort the list returned by a saved job search.